# Are there underground mobs in peaceful difficulty?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In peaceful, can you find mobs underground in caves? I know they don't spawn on the surface if you have the difficulty set to peaceful on pocket edition but I was wondering if there was any below the surface.

Answer (score 5):

No. There are no hostile mobs at all in peaceful. Any hostile mobs that are spawned in are also immediately despawned.

Comment: No *hostile* mobs.

Comment: @tombull89 Fixed.